# Center-align a Paper component inside a div

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I can not center my `<Paper>` inside div. Please help

I locate `<Paper>` and `<RaisedButton>` inside div and gave with css:

```
.timerArea {
  text-align: center;
}
```

For Button it works but for Paper - no.

Style for `<Paper>`

```
const timeArea = {
  height: 150,
  width: 150,
  textAlign: 'center',
  rounded: true,
  paddingTop: 65,
  backgroundColor: '#76D8E3',
  opacity: 0.8
};
```

Also my JSX:

```
<div className={styles.timerArea}>
  <Paper style={timeArea} zDepth={1} circle>{stopWatchTime}</Paper>
  <RaisedButton onClick={buttonRole} backgroundColor={buttonColor}>{buttonName}</RaisedButton>
</div>
```

and result on the image [image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try "margin: auto" in paper style

Comment: thanks, it works.

Please write it as an answer and I'll mark it as helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try margin auto in paper style like this

```
const timeArea = {
  height: 150,
  width: 150,
  textAlign: 'center',
  rounded: true,
  paddingTop: 65,
  backgroundColor: '#76D8E3',
  opacity: 0.8,
  margin: auto,
};
```